# install python Jupyter notebook or anaconda navigator on informatica server

Tags: python, windows, informatica

Currently we have installed native python on informatica server and tried calling using infa command (Python)task. It's all working fine. But the native python has basic modules which will not suffice our requirement.

If we install anaconda navigator or Jupiter notebook on infa server can we execute all python scripts without installing the modules on native python?

Comment: The user that runs infa should have execute permission on those modules.

Comment: that says, no need to install modules on native python correct?

Comment: all depends on the user running informatica services having access to executables

Comment: I'd rather recommend creating a VirtualEnv and running all your scripts within it.